# Buton Css not working html color and padding is not working

Tags: html, css

My button is not displaying any css and I am clueless why they are not. For reference, here is the html code:

```css
p.B3 {
    padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebDocTitle</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1.css"/>
</head>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2328.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText1</button>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2329.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText2</button>
</html>
```

Comment: It's supposed to be "p .b3" instead "p.b3", add a space in between in your styles.

Comment: Just a side note on usability: If clicking these texts changes the page, a link would be expected, which is way more powerful than a button, in that it allows opening in new tabs, copying the URL to send it to a colleague or another device, bookmark it, etc. [ Buttons vs. Links ](https://css-tricks.com/buttons-vs-links/)

Answer (score 1):

Dude, it's working fine there is no issue in your code just add `space` after `p` tag in CSS.

```css
p .B3 {
    padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebDocTitle</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1.css"/>
</head>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2328.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText1</button>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2329.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText2</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I am new to HTML so i got confused. This helped

Answer (score 0):

Man just put a space b/w p .B3']

You can learn more from this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

(NB: You don't even need `p` can just use
.B3 {
padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}

)

AFTER :-

```css
p .B3 {
    padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebDocTitle</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1.css"/>
</head>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2328.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText1</button>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2329.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText2</button>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer currently doesn’t explain what the error was. If the questioner didn’t use the space, they might not know the difference. Mind to explain the [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.B3 {
    padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2328.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText1</button>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2329.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText2</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
button.B3 {
    padding: 50px; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow; border-radius: 50% font-family: cooper black; font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebDocTitle</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1.css"/>
</head>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2328.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText1</button>
<p align=center> <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='%2329.HTML';" class="B3">ButtonText2</button>
</html>
```